# What to do about multiple editors who approve edits that butcher the original post?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I certainly don't mean to rant, so if it sounds that way then I apologize. I'd just like to know what to do, if anything, about the (multiple) editors who approve an edit such as the one found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15513) which:

- claims to have "Improved formatting", when in fact no changes to the code's format were made
- butchers the original grammatical structure of the post

I understand the process for remedying the post itself (i.e. another editor will change it again or revert it), but when a problem like this persists wherein three users -- the original editor and the two approving editors -- accept/approve an edit that is clearly unsatisfactory, to whose attention should this be brought (if anyone's at all)? Or is there an alternative method?

Thanks in advance... You guys rock.

:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just roll it back - as the original author, you can do that fairly easily. You might also want to leave a comment notifying the editor that this edit was not helpful.

You can also check the past activity of both the editor and the reviewers who approved the edit - if you find a lot of junk / abusive / pointless edits, flag one or more of the posts involved so that the moderators can deal with them.

Comment: Can we please please please please please please ban "Improved formatting" and some grammatical variations?  I almost want to reject any edit that has the comment regardless of whether it is valid or not simply because 75% of the worst edits seem to have that exact comment when they have nothing to do with code formatting.

Comment: Then what do I write when I'm improving formatting? Also, blame the folks who approve this stuff without reading the comment.

Comment: Of course you are right.... I just hate seeing that comment because it is usually meaningless

Comment: Or we just black list it for suggested edits :-)

Comment: Blacklist it, and it'll be replaced with some other meaningless comment. FWIW, moderators can block reviewers who don't pay attention - so the reviewer stats that show up on suggested edits (and the activity histories of those involved) are worth looking at when you see a bad one.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, @Shog9. Very much appreciated.