# Should/do we discourage edits, by privileged users or not, to off-topic questions that will end up deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, off-topic

**This is not a duplicate of [Is "don't polish turds" a valid rejection reason"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason).**  We want to prevent those edits from getting into the queue in the first place.  That also focuses primarily on suggested edits; this one includes ones from privileged users and a suggestion that we put a "When not to edit" section in the [edit privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) page.

---

Over the past few days, I've seen a couple of privileged users making edits, significant or not, to off-topic posts that have ended up deleted (here on MSE and elsewhere).  I personally think we should discourage these edits for a couple of reasons, some of them the same as the ones for not editing spam....

Sometimes, this sets a precedent of allowing sub-2K users without edit privileges to suggest edits.  These edits can be decent, or just basically crap that wastes reviewers' time.  [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79515) a case in point, and this happens on SO as well (though that's from other people's posts because I'm sub-2K on SO/MSO).  There are a few other reasons, including the one about edits making an off-topic/spam post ["good"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110031/798831), but that's the primary one for me.

So, perhaps we could *officially* discourage behavior like this, with regard to *everyone* editing?  I'd suggest adding a section in the [edit privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) called "When not to edit", listing the reasons why you shouldn't edit spam-R/A posts, off-topic posts, etc., made by the fine people across SE.

Other related stuff:

- A [comment](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8675103#8675103) in chat about why sub-2K users shouldn't edit off-topic posts.
- Another [comment](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1522505#1522505).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason

Comment: Personally, I used to not agree with the answer to the duplicate question, because it didn't consider the fact that edits to closed questions *used to* usurp the question's one entry by edit into the reopen queue. Now that an edit to a closed question doesn't always automatically push the question into the reopen review queue, I'm substantially less against such edits. They are something of a waste of time, but some of the edits aren't (e.g. an edit helps with formatting and then the OP makes a substantial edit, but wouldn't have known about or how to fix formatting issues).

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214065/rejected-edits-should-have-consequences

Comment: The comment thread was chatty and has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1609/discussion-on-question-by-ollie-should-do-we-discourage-edits-by-privileged-use). I've kept what felt like what was pertinent to someone trying to quickly catch up with the main thrust of the comment thread, and what may be appropriate potential dupes.

Comment: People, especially those who are volunteering their time and talent to contribute value to something, should be allowed to spend their time as they please so long as it doesn't harm someone, even if their desired activity is a waste of time. I realized long ago that discouraging people from doing annoying things doesn't reduce the amount of time I spend being annoyed as effectively as changing my own attitude. If someone enjoys correcting text, correcting an off topic post is no different from doing a crossword then tossing the newspaper (now that it doesn't automatically go in the queue).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Frankly - my opinion is, if people want to waste their time polishing turds and making silk purses from sow ears and other metaphors, they're welcome to.

I would suggest that getting trivial edits/edits to questions that don't belong not being approved, or losing the rep for a suggested edit as posts are deleted might even be part of the learning curve for a new user using suggested edits to learn the ropes of editing. It might feel a bit harsh but that's kinda how the feedback loop is.

As an experienced user "it bothers the heck out of me" is a perfectly valid edit reason.

Answer (score 9):

Edits like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79515) (the "case in point" in the question) should be rejected regardless of the question's off-topic-ness, because that edit did not improve the quality of the post.  I would have rejected that edit on Stack Overflow too. All it did was change the not-quite-grammatical "why not able to" to the also-not-quite-grammatical "why cant we" and add a "using" to a place that was correct with or without it.  It did nothing about the block of completely unformatted code that was the entire question body, which was a much larger problem than minor quibbles over the title's phrasing.

As far as edits that make *actual* improvements go, I'd say:

- For completely off-topic questions (i.e., no amount of editing will ever make the question suitable), I don't think there's a wrong answer.  Approve them if you like, reject them if they annoy you.  Most of them will end up deleted and the user won't get to keep the rep anyway.
- For on-topic questions where some *meaningful* improvement is made, but not enough to warrant reopening, approve the edit: it makes it easier for an edit that *does* fix the rest of the issues.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @JourneymanGeek.

If users over 2k reputation edit off-topic questions that would end up deleted, it's their choice, it doesn't necessarily help the site but it doesn't obviously harm it.

But if it's a user with less than 2k rep, either:

1. The edit suggestions usually take a long time, and if the OP has written a really off-topic question, normally they wouldn't know/care about approving suggested edits. So even before it gets approved/rejected the post would be already deleted.
2. Sometimes the edit suggestions might get approved before deletion of the post, but then obviously once the question is deleted the reputation is gone. Exactly as @JourneymanGeek mentioned,

   *"losing the rep for a suggested edit as posts are deleted might even be part of the learning curve for a new user using suggested edits to learn the ropes of editing."*